# Как установить Pug в Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, pug

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- node.js v11.1.0
- npm v6.4.1

Пытаюсь установить `Pug` с помощью команды:

```
sudo npm install pug
```

Через пару минут установка доходит примерно до 60% и зависает (больше часа никакой реакции).

```
npm WARN tarball tarball data for decamelize@^1.0.0 (sha1-9lNNFRSCabIDUue+4m9QH5oZEpA=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
[            ......] - extract:core-js: WARN tarball tarball data for decamelize@^1.0.0 (sha1-9lNNFRSCabIDUue+4m9QH5oZEpA=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
```

Хотя если установить `decamelize` напрямую

```
sudo npm install decamelize
```

то установка проходит без проблем (хотя устанавливается версия 2.0.0).

Можно ли как-то скачать пакет `Pug` не через терминал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогли следующие команды:

1. Чистим кэш менеджера пакетов

---

```
$ npm cache clean --force
$ npm install --force --verbose --no-bin-links
```

2. Устанавливаем нужные пакеты последних версий

---

```
$ npm install pug@2.0.3
$ npm install pug-cli@1.0.0-alpha6 -g
```

3. Создаем ссылку на пакет

---

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v11.1.0/bin/pug /usr/bin/pug
```

**Результат**:

```
$ pug -V
pug version: 2.0.3
pug-cli version: 1.0.0-alpha6
```